# How to find the fixed element for Galois group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This is extension of my question of the link [How to find the fixed field for Galois group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303469/how-to-find-the-fixed-field-for-galois-group)

(I've already solved the question (1))

**Question**) Duplicated

Let be $K$ the finite splitting field of $f(x) (\in \Bbb Q[x])$ over the field, $\Bbb Q$(rational number set)

And say $E_H$ is a fixed field of   $H\subset \operatorname{Gal}(K/Q) $.

Find the fixed field  $E_H$

$f(x) = x^8 +1$, $H= \{ \sigma_1,   \sigma_7 ,\sigma_9,  \sigma_{15 }  \}$

with$\sigma_n (\omega) =  \omega  \to \omega^n $ for $\omega = e^{{2\pi i} \over 16} $ and $gcd(n,16)=1$

I'm already knew the $\operatorname{Gal}(K/Q) \simeq Z_2 \times Z_4$

Also the $E_H \simeq Z_2 \times Z_2$

But I have a problem that finding the exact fixed element and field.

(I.E. All I have to do is the fixed element for finding the fixed field )

I can't figure out the how to take it. Cause the calculating process really complicated.

*How to find the fixed element?*

**p.s.)** Here is my process(This method is really complicated.)

First) Express the field's element, $x$ by the linear combination of the basis

Second) Find the $x$ $s.t. \sigma (x)=x$  by comparing coefficent for $\sigma \in  \operatorname{Gal}(K/Q) $

Comment: As hinted at in my answer to your other question, you should first determine the structure of $\operatorname{Gal} K/ℚ$. Then it will be really easy to see what $K^H$.

Comment: @k.stm.  Yes, thanks for your hint,I knew the structure of the $G(K/ Q) $$\simeq Z_2 \times Z_4$ And Also $K^H \simeq Z_2 \times Z_2$. So By Galois thm, I could conclude that the $[K^H ; Q] =2$ and $[K^H ; Q(\omega)]=4$. But couldn't find the exact $K^H$.

Comment: @k.stm, Like your kind explanation, Finding the structure of the Galois group is the first step. But I have a serious problem the second step that which find the exact fixed element and its field .I'm gonna edit my post.

Comment: Pick an element $x$ in $K$. Calculate $y=\sum_{\sigma{\rm\ in\ }H}\sigma(x)$. Then $y$ will be in the fixed field of $H$. If you're lucky, $y$ will generate the fixed field. If you're unlucky, pick a different $x$, and try again.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang Ah, yes. Thanks for your edit. And you’re right. It’s not so easy then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A canonical basis for $K$ is $B = \{1, \omega, \omega^2,\ldots,\omega^7 \}$. Consider the map $\mathcal{S}: K \rightarrow E_H: u \mapsto \sum_{h \in H}{h(u)}$. $E_H$ is then generated by the vectors $\mathcal{S}(B)$. In this case they are $\{  4, 0, 2\omega^2-2\omega^6, 0, 0, 0, -2\omega^2+2\omega^6, 0 \}$ and all of them are fixed by $H$. To extract an independent set of them, in order to obtain a basis for $E_H$, one can choose for example the set $\{1,\omega^2-\omega^6\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $K/\Bbb{Q}$ Galois, once you have a normal basis for $K/\Bbb{Q}$, that is some $a \in K$ such that $$K = \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(K/Q)} \sigma(a) \Bbb{Q}$$ then since the trace $Tr_{K/K^H}(b)= \sum_{h \in H} h(b)$ is surjective $K \to K^H$ $$K^H = \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(K/Q)} Tr_{K/K^H}(\sigma(a))\Bbb{Q}= \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(K/Q)/ H} Tr_{K/K^H}(\sigma(a))\Bbb{Q} = \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(K/Q)/ H} (\sum_{h \in H} h\sigma_j(a)) \Bbb{Q}$$
If instead you start from a primitive element $K = \Bbb{Q}(c)$ then $K = \sum_{j=1}^n c^j \Bbb{Q}$ so that $$K^H = \sum_{j=1}^n Tr_{K/K^H}(c^j) \Bbb{Q}=\Bbb{Q}(Tr_{K/K^H}(c),\ldots, Tr_{K/K^H}(c^n))$$